# How do I describe this the anger of this person?

Tags: sentence

I want to describe a angry person. He was very angry. His eyes wide opens, he bits his lips, and his fists hold tight.

Comment: Thanks. But, I need to show his anger, not to tell. In another words, I need to describe his how angry he is.

Comment: You did describe such in your question.

Comment: One great oft overlooked word: iracund.

Comment: You could say that he was so angry he had just eaten the TV. I think that would get the message across.

Comment: @Lambie ... and with good reason, I would venture to say.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the writing forum.

Answer (score 3):

**Apoplectic**

He was apoplectic with rage.

Apoplectic pertains to apoplexy which means (from [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/apoplexy))

> 3. A fit of extreme anger; rage: "The proud ... members suffered collective apoplexy, and this year they are out for blood" (David Finch).

It’s anger so powerful as to have similar effects as a neurological attack. Muscle contractions such as clenched fists and teeth seem to fit this definition.

Comment: This word is often misquoted as 'apopleptic', I have noticed.